# Possible to save jQuery objects even after removing from DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

As title says, I have selected a group of elements using a jQuery selector.

All of these elements are children of a div that I am about to 'clear out' using .html('');

This means I'll lose the elements, but I want to then append them to another element later on, how do I save these elements?

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="sub-div">
<div class="contentdiv">
</div>
</div>
<div class="sub-div">
<div class="contentdiv">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ultimately, I want to clear out 'parent' and then insert the contentDiv's back into there. And you must assume there are an arbitrary amount of sub-div divs, so it literally needs to be a case of clearing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.remove()` instead. This allows you to keep a reference to the elements. The DOM Nodes wont be destroyed. You can re-append them with `.append`.

It's analogous to `.removeChild`.

Comment: Was just about to write this => +1

Comment: I want to remove other divs inside this parent div aswell though. +1. My fault, I should've specified this parent div needed clearing out altogether.

Comment: Then do it in a loop. It doesn't really matter much, you need the references either way.

Answer (score -2):

You can only hide them using hide() and show later, or other way you want.
Other solution in my mind is keeping those elements in some kind of string array. Then u can just append them into html.